# write html content to NSString and display on iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

i have a webveiw where i can show small html value but i have a issue

if is do this

```
NSString *HTMLData =@"<h3><span style=font-family:Helvetica-Bold > <strong> Information</strong> </span></h3>";


    HTMLData= [HTMLData stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];


    [web loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:nil];
```

then its wokring fine

but if my NSString has a break line lets say

```
    NSString *HTMLData =@"<h3><span style=font-family:Helvetica-Bold >
 <strong> Information</strong>
 </span></h3>";
```

then i am getting error how to avoid this error???
**my error is missing terminator charcter**

Answer (score 1):

To break long NSStrings across multiple lines, you need to put double quotes at the end and beginning of each line:

```
NSString *HTMLData =@"<h3><span style=font-family:Helvetica-Bold >"
    "<strong> Information</strong>"
    "</span></h3>";
```

**Edit:**
An example with NSMutableString:

```
NSMutableString *HTMLData = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
[HTMLData appendString:@"<h3><span style=font-family:Helvetica-Bold >"];
[HTMLData appendString:@"<strong> Information</strong>"];
[HTMLData appendString:@"</span></h3>"];
//more appends...

//do something with HTMLData here

[HTMLData release];
```

The initWithCapacity just tells how many characters to allocate space for initially (it's not a limit).

NSMutableString also has the `appendFormat:` method which works like `stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: but lets say i have a whole 200 lines of html tag then same way??? ooh god any short cut method

Comment: You could also use an NSMutableString and append one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this could be simply write your HTML as an String. 
and show the string as an Attributed String for Label.

```
let htmlText = "<p>etc</p>"

if let htmlData = htmlText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding) {
    do {
        someLabel.attributedText = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlData,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch let e as NSError {
        print("Couldn't translate \(htmlText): \(e.localizedDescription) ")
    }
}
```

reference :  [How to show an HTML string on a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301145/how-to-show-an-html-string-on-a-uilabel?lq=1)