# How to show an HTML string on a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UILabel`. And I want to set a string that also contains some `HTML` tags in it. The string is:

```
NSString *str = @"<p>Hey you. My <b>name </b> is <h1> Joe </h1></p>";
```

How can i display this on the `UILabel`

```
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];



    mylabel.attributedText=attrStr;
```

The above code doesn't display anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789447/write-html-content-to-nsstring-and-display-on-iphone . Hope will helpful to you.

Comment: Doesn't display anything? Is `attrStr` nil? What about using `error` parameter? Is `myLabel` nil?

Comment: if `UILabel` doesn't work in your case then why don't you use `UIWebView` which is made for it? Just disable the scrolling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UILabel text as html text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743844/uilabel-text-as-html-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For iOS7 or more you can use this:

```
NSString * htmlString = @" <p><b>Hey</b> you. My <b>name </b> is <h1> Joe </h1></p> ";
    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];


UILabel * myLabel = [UILabel alloc] init];
myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Its works

Comment: There's a similar answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946251/how-to-show-an-html-string-on-a-uilabel-in-ios But, it doesn;t work

Comment: I recently test it on ios 8.4 and then post a comment if you want screen shot then check it below link 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfu029l3g7z64cm/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-23%20at%205.08.54%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: I didn't test with uilabel, I'm certainly sure it works with regard to UITextView

Answer (score 2):

You should used following code. it's help you!!
Apple provided document and link for NSAttributedString.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-initwithdata

```
NSString * htmlString = @"You added a note - in <a href='http://localhost:80/ABC/phase2/public/users/Test/notes/5'>hfgh</a>";
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Comment: Please also describe your solution, not just type the code.